# 2) Create data frame using following object

Tags: r, dataframe

Create data frame using following objects.

```
workshop <- c("R", " SPSS ", NA , " SPSS ", " STATA ", " SPSS ") 
gender <- factor (c(" Female ", " Male ", NA , " Female ", " Female ", " Female ") ) 
q1 <- c(4 , 3 , 3 , 5 , 4 , 5) 
q2 <- c(3 , 4 , 2 , 4 , 4 , 4) 
q3 <- c(4 , 3 , NA , 5 , 3, 3) 
q4 <- c(5 , 4 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 5)
```

a)  Create a dataframe consisting of only the first two columns.

b)  Create a dataframe consisting of only the first and last row.

c)  Create a dataframe called df2 where every entry in the q3 and q4 columns is 0.

d)  Sort df by gender.

Comment: This seems like a homework question, what code have you already written yourself?